# Run route angularjs without server

Tags: angularjs, routes

I need to run this router without nodejs server. Is it possible. All other files for routing having in the same directory.But it is not routing with the certain url to desired pages. Also the first page 'online_exam_1.html' content is not displaying while I am open this page with browser.

```
<html data-ng-app="demoApp" >
<head>
 <title>
Online Exam Syatem 
</title>

</head>
<body ><div class="container" ng-controller="RoutingController">
    <div>
        <h3>Adding Module Configuration and Routing</h3>
        <!-- ng-view handles loading partials into it based
             upon routes -->
        <div data-ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="angular.min.js">
<script src="angular_route.js"> </script>
</script>
<script>
    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        alert('in');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'RoutingController',
                    templateUrl: urlBase + 'online_exam_1.html'
                })
            //Define a route that has a route parameter in it (:customerID)
            .when('/2',
                {
                    controller: 'RoutingController',
                    templateUrl: urlBase + 'online_exam_2.html'
                })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/partial1' });
    });

    demoApp.controller('RoutingController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            { name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix' },
            { name: 'Jamie Riley', city: 'Atlanta' },
            { name: 'Heedy Wahlin', city: 'Chandler' },
            { name: 'Thomas Winter', city: 'Seattle' }
        ];
    });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the errors? Are you perhaps getting `404`'s in your Network tab?

Comment: There is no error just not displaying any ouput from online_exam_1.html page.. or online_exam_2.html page